# What are currently the problems with Git on Windows

Tags: git, version-control

I wanted to download msysgit [here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/), and it says this: "here are not enough contributors to the msysGit project to offer commercial-grade support; if you do not have the means to fix your problems (possibly with valuable advice from the msysGit mailing list), or to entice people who can fix them, it is unlikely that your problem gets solved. "

This sounds discouraging. Why is that? What are the issues? Is everyone using another distributed source control system?

Edit:

I watched the following video [Tech Talk: Linus Torvalds on git](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XpnKHJAok8). Linus highly recommends git.
I don't understand the votes to close the question - git is a programmers tool and as such should belong her, right?

Comment: I think you should ask superuser.com.

Comment: @zneak: Git has nothing to do with SU. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61720/where-should-questions-about-software-development-tools-go. @Alex: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704565/why-kiln-is-based-on-mercurial-and-not-other-dvcs/1704687#1704687 for a bit of context.

Comment: I don't see a question in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote you mention is referring more to problems that *you* create. A huge purpose of "commercial-grade support" is to have someone to contact when you can't figure out how to dig yourself out of the hole you dove into. The developers naturally can't and have no desire to fill that role, and that quote is really just them trying to fend off waves of emails from people saying "I ran `git clean -xdf` and all my files are gone! Help!" An actual bug report would be a very different matter - they want their software to work just as much as you do.

All that said, msysgit is based on the git everyone else uses, which has a pretty extensive test suite. I think you can count on it for stability as much as you can any VCS at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using git on Win7 with no obvious problems.  Don't let the language scare you.  Get it, try it.  I don't think you'll be sorry.

Edit: Download it from http://git-scm.com

Comment: Well I am responsible for my system, and sometimes I must be able to do things real quick. My version control must be rock solid. So if the windows version of this wonderful  tool is half baked I cannot go for it. In your estimate, how many people are using git on windows?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you used TortoiseGit?

https://tortoisegit.org

Comment: Confused. Does that answer the question? What are you trying to say?

Comment: If you are satsfied, please upvote ;] I wrote about TortoiseGit, because I work with it on Windows and don't have any problems. Maybe creators of it solved some of errors inside msysgit?

Answer (score 1):

msysgit has been really stable for us. However the team working on it does seem to be very small (and we're very grateful to them). If they were to move off the project, who knows what would happen. So far so good though.

We have hit a bug in gitk where our repo has so many changes that gitk on Windows won't show them all, whereas on a Mac it will. Something to do with the command line length limit on Windows. We'll see whether it gets fixed or not. Still, there's TortoiseGit which works and offers an alternate UI.

I would recommend it, with the caveat that you also look into Mercurial, which is perhaps better supported on Windows.