# Is git stable on Windows?

Tags: windows, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are currently the problems with Git on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696834/what-are-currently-the-problems-with-git-on-windows)

Recently, I've been considering switching our source control system from svn to git so that we can leverage the feature of distributability. After I did some investigations. I found that, it seems we don't have much choice on running git on the Windows. Only one option that balances on both side of learning curve and administrative effort is msysGit. Unfortunately, It's still on the preview version so far.

Do I miss something? Or, is there a better alternative?

Comment: SO question about problems of Git on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696834/what-are-currently-the-problems-with-git-on-windows

Comment: I've been using msysGit heavily for both work and play for over a year now and have never had one problem. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Agree with @Matt Greer above. It works wonderfully for me and I have yet to hit a single issue.

Comment: it's very stable, I've been using it for over a year with no issues.

Comment: I think the real question is why msysgit is perpetually marked as preview releases.

Comment: My company also uses MSysGit with [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/), and we are very happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use mSysGit and have been for about a year. We've run into some bugs, but no blockers -- the repository has always been pretty solid; the bugs are all in the front-end tools.

The two bugs we've run into are:

- The GUI apps (git-gui and gitk) both lock up from time to time, usually several times a day. The lock-ups only happen when you're trying to do something with the repository: stage a change, do a commit, check out a branch, etc. This seems to be a deadlock in the communication between the GUI app and the command-line process that actually does the work. When the GUI stops responding, all you have to do is kill it and start it again. I have never seen this cause any data corruption -- it seems to be just the GUI app that's locking up; the command-line app either finishes its work or doesn't start. This is harmless but annoying, and apparently the mSysGit maintainers can't reproduce it (though I've seen it on every computer I've tried Git on).
- Occasionally, when you check out a different branch, Git will silently fail to create all the new branch's files on disk; so if you look at the status, you'll see a "deleted" file (I don't think I've ever seen more than one or two) ready to be staged. I've never run into this from the command line, so I don't know if the checkout is giving some warning, but if you check out from the GUI there's no sign that anything is wrong unless you rescan for unstaged changes. This happens fairly rarely (perhaps once a week), but you'll notice it when you're staging your changes, before it can do any damage. The file is still there in the repository; you just need to reset (or revert changes on that file) to put it back in your working copy.

Both are merely annoyances; you don't need to be especially vigilant for them, you just need the patience to clean up when they happen.

Comment: This isn't too surprising, since an awful lot of Git is written in C, and so most of the core is the same code compiled on Windows instead. (Obviously portability can sometimes be a nightmare, but still!)