# Is Kiln for your server being retired?

Tags: fogbugz, kiln, installed-applications, hosted-app

I was looking into the [Kiln Harmony feature](http://blog.fogcreek.com/announcing-kiln-harmony-the-future-of-dvcs) and saw that FogCreek only advertises it in On Demand. In the "How do you get it" section they don't even mention that it is not available for the On Premise version.

So I went looking for details of the "Kiln on your Server" pricing to see what was included. I can't even find pricing for the licensing anymore. Is the hosted version now the only Kiln available?

I submitted the same question to customer service, but I didn't get an answer back yet.

**http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/pricing.html**

It has this blurb of text saying:

> Try Kiln now for a full 45 days free — fully featured, unlimited users, and no credit card required.
>   Looking for Kiln for Your Server? Learn More.

When you click on "Learn More" you get

> Kiln is currently available via On Demand. If you currently use FogBugz for your server and would like more information about moving to the On Demand environment so that your team can use Kiln, please contact us.

We are using FogBugz and Kiln on our server, so this is troublesome, and I would like to understand if I am just seeing things.

Comment: Did you ever hear back from FogCreek on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We've contacted FogCreek about our "for-your-server" installation & have been told that they've stopped selling "for-your-server" & that existing "for-your-server" customers will be only receiving bugfixes, not enhancements.

Comment: It would have been nice if they had emailed their "for-your-server" customers to tell them that. It's been radio silence. Last time I asked (in Sept 13) I was told it was under review. They suggested moving to On Demand but the cost is 900% more... We've already moved our source control over to GitHub (ironically using a free Kiln Harmony account to convert our repos from Hg to Git). It's only a matter of time until we move our FogBugz content elsewhere. You can't run a business on an unsupported product.

Comment: Kiln For Your Server would seem to be in pretty high demand as is observed by the top rated but completely ignored issue on competitor Atlassian's product site. https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2469