# Git fetch a branch once with a normal name, and once with capital letter

Tags: git, case-insensitive, git-fetch, remote-branch

I'm fetching for remote branches and stuck in some sort of a loop.

I fetch once and get:

```
$ git fetch
* [new branch]      minorRelease/something-> origin/minorRelease/something
```

And then I fetch again and get:

```
$ git fetch
* [new branch]      minorRelease/Something-> origin/minorRelease/Something
```

Same branch but with a capital `S`.

I tried to delete the file from the following folder `.git/refs/remotes/origin/minorRelease`, but when fetching again, I get both and return to the loop above:

```
$ git fetch
* [new branch]      minorRelease/Something-> origin/minorRelease/Something
* [new branch]      minorRelease/something-> origin/minorRelease/something
```

Comment: What platform are you using? Is its file system case-insensitive?

Comment: Windows 7, using git bash. Remote server runs ubuntu I think.

Comment: What does `git remote --verbose show origin | grep "tracked"` tell you?

Comment: This is not an answer (I don't have or use Windows) but generally git stuffs branch information into files.  Ubuntu file systems are case-sensitive so if there are two branches `Abc` and `abc` they are different branches, while Windows (and some MacOS) file systems are generally case-insensitive so `Abc` and `abc` are the same branch.  This certainly *could* lead to the issue you're seeing.  The workaround would be to make sure no one creates two different branches differing only in case, on the server.

Comment: Another option is to switch to an OS that supports a case-insensitive filesystem. Hint: not Windows `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs - In `git remote` I get `minorRelease/Something`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@torek` is right that it's caused by the difference of `Linux` and `Windows`. `Linux` is case-sensitive, while `Windows` is not. You can use `ls-remote` to show the branches in the server.

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

And I think in your case, the output should include the two branches with only the case of `S` different.

```
ref/heads/minorRelease/Something
ref/heads/minorRelease/something
```

You can delete the remote branch if you find one of them is actually duplicated. And then do `fetch` again. It should be fine now.

```
git push origin :minorRelease/Something
git fetch
```

Comment: The too were duplicated, so I deleted the one with the lower case (capital first letter is our convention). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note: with Git 2.12 (Q1 2017) this will become easier to spot, as you can list branch with a case insensitive option.

See [commit 3bb16a8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3bb16a8bf2ec02c4cc633c3efd4c012e55ee0c2d) (04 Dec 2016) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 73e494f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73e494f86239b7edcf44f4c185c997b05c0e763b), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> `tag`, `branch`, `for-each-ref`: add `--ignore-case` for sorting and filtering.
>   **This options makes sorting ignore case, which is great when you have
>   branches named `bug-12-do-something`, `Bug-12-do-some-more` and
>   `BUG-12-do-what` and want to group them together**.
>   Sorting externally may not be an option because we lose coloring and column layout from git-branch and git-tag.
>
> The same could be said for filtering, but it's probably less important because you can always go with the ugly pattern `[bB][uU][gG]-*` if you're desperate.
>
> You can't have case-sensitive filtering and case-insensitive sorting (or
>   the other way around) with this though. For `branch` and `tag`, that should
>   be no problem. `for-each-ref`, as a plumbing, might want finer control.
>   But we can always add `--{filter,sort}-ignore-case` when there is a need
>   for it.

```
git branch --ignore-case --list
```

---

Note: The "`--ignore-case`" option of "`git for-each-ref`" (and its friends)
did not work correctly, which has been fixed in Git 2.19 (Q3 2018).

See [commit 639ab5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/639ab5efa1ad79bd69abfd67bf28016db41c10d5) (02 Jul 2018) by [Aleksandr Makarov (`deviance`)](https://github.com/deviance).
See [commit e674eb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e674eb2528229ac7f9c911369a39e7a979bfe75a), [commit ee0f3e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee0f3e22c61f73734f3caa6c3f5c7a224227ce38) (02 Jul 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4301330](https://github.com/git/git/commit/43013305887c2b81858a0741f39872f8ed5f27d6), 24 Jul 2018)</sup>

> ### `ref-filter`: avoid backend filtering with `--ignore-case`
>
> When `for-each-ref` is used with `--ignore-case`, we expect `match_name_as_path()` to do a case-insensitive match.
>   But there's an extra layer of filtering that happens before we even get there. Since [commit cfe004a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfe004a5a9e5116d003332a64142b0f73f8f9cdf) (`ref-filter`: limit traversal to prefix, 2017-05-22, Git v2.14.0), we feed the prefix to the ref backend so that it can optimize the ref iteration.
>
> There's no mechanism for us to tell the backend we're matching
>   case-insensitively.  Nor is there likely to be one anytime soon,
>   since the packed backend relies on binary-searching the sorted list
>   of refs.
>   Let's just punt on this case. The extra filtering is an
>   optimization that we simply can't do. We'll still give the correct
>   answer via the filtering in `match_name_as_path(`).

---

Note that, with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), "`git for-each-ref`" with multiple patterns have been optimized.

See [commit b31e268](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b31e2680c46c43ece716080040e90b3a787b0bad) (26 Jun 2019) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b4b8c35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4b8c35729985a8f1f5e22f82259a2499efbc37a), 19 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `ref-filter.c`: find disjoint pattern prefixes
>
> Since [cfe004a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfe004a5a9e5116d003332a64142b0f73f8f9cdf) (`ref-filter`: limit traversal to prefix, 2017-05-22, Git v2.14.0-rc0), the `ref-filter` code has sought to limit the traversals to a prefix of the given patterns.
>
> That code stopped short of handling more than one pattern, because it means invoking 'for_each_ref_in' multiple times.
>   If we're not careful about which patterns overlap, we will output the same refs multiple times.
>
> For instance, consider the set of patterns 'refs/heads/a/*',
>   'refs/heads/a/b/c', and 'refs/tags/v1.0.0'. If we naïvely ran:
>
> ```
>   for_each_ref_in("refs/heads/a/*", ...);
>   for_each_ref_in("refs/heads/a/b/c", ...);
>   for_each_ref_in("refs/tags/v1.0.0", ...);
> ```
>
> we would see '`refs/heads/a/b/c`' (and everything underneath it) twice.
>
> Instead, we want to partition the patterns into disjoint sets, where we
>   know that no ref will be matched by any two patterns in different sets.
>   In the above, these are:
>
> - `{'refs/heads/a/*', 'refs/heads/a/b/c'}`, and
> - `{'refs/tags/v1.0.0'}`
>
> Given one of these disjoint sets, what is a suitable pattern to pass to
>   '`for_each_ref_in`'?
>
> One approach is to compute the longest common prefix over all elements in that disjoint set, and let the caller cull out the refs they didn't want.
>   Computing the longest prefix means that in most cases, we won't match too many things the caller would like to ignore.
>
> The longest common prefixes of the above are:
>
> - `{'refs/heads/a/*', 'refs/heads/a/b/c'} -> refs/heads/a/*`
> - `{'refs/tags/v1.0.0'}                   -> refs/tags/v1.0.0`
>
> We instead invoke:
>
> ```
>   for_each_ref_in("refs/heads/a/*", ...);
>   for_each_ref_in("refs/tags/v1.0.0", ...);
> ```
>
> Which provides us with the refs we were looking for with a minimal amount of extra cruft, but never a duplicate of the ref we asked for.
>
> Implemented here is an algorithm which accomplishes the above, which
>   works as follows:
>
> 1. Lexicographically sort the given list of patterns.
> 2. Initialize 'prefix' to the empty string, where our goal is to
>       build each element in the above set of longest common prefixes.
> 3. Consider each pattern in the given set, and emit 'prefix' if it
>       reaches the end of a pattern, or touches a wildcard character. The
>       end of a string is treated as if it precedes a wildcard. (Note that
>       there is some room for future work to detect that, e.g., 'a?b' and
>       'abc' are disjoint).
> 4. Otherwise, recurse on step `(3)` with the slice of the list
>       corresponding to our current prefix (i.e., the subset of patterns
>       that have our prefix as a literal string prefix.)
>
> This algorithm is '`O(kn + n log(n))`', where '`k`' is `max(len(pattern))` for
>   each pattern in the list, and '`n`' is `len(patterns)`.
>
> By discovering this set of interesting patterns, we reduce the runtime
>   of multi-pattern '`git for-each-ref`' (and other ref traversals) from
>   `O(N)` to `O(n log(N))`, where '`N`' is the total number of packed references.
>
> Running 'git for-each-ref refs/tags/a refs/tags/b' on a repository with
>   10,000,000 refs in 'refs/tags/huge-N', my best-of-five times drop from:
>
> ```
>   real    0m5.805s
>   user    0m5.188s
>   sys     0m0.468s
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
>   real    0m0.001s
>   user    0m0.000s
>   sys     0m0.000s
> ```
>
> On `linux.git`, the times to dig out two of the latest `-rc` tags drops from
>   0.002s to 0.001s, so the change on repositories with fewer tags is much
>   less noticeable.

---

"`git branch`" and other "`for-each-ref`" variants accepted multiple `--sort=<key>` options in the increasing order of precedence, but it had a few breakages around "`--ignore-case`" handling, and tie-breaking with the refname, which have been fixed with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

See [commit 7c5045f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c5045fc180ed09ed4cb5065955acddc1dd50163), [commit 76f9e56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76f9e569adb540a1ca1a590c512d57fce4eea878) (03 May 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6de1630](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6de1630898838b62b97617323a07eb6fe9618a7e), 08 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76f9e569adb540a1ca1a590c512d57fce4eea878): apply `--ignore-case` to *all* sorting keys
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> All of the `ref-filter` users (`for-each-ref`, `branch`, and `tag`) take an `--ignore-case` option which makes filtering and sorting case-insensitive.
>
> **However, this option was applied only to the first element of the `ref_sorting` list**.
>
> So:
>
> ```
> git for-each-ref --ignore-case --sort=refname
> ```
>
> would do what you expect, but:
>
> ```
> git for-each-ref --ignore-case --sort=refname --sort=taggername
> ```
>
> would sort the primary key (taggername) case-insensitively, but sort the refname case-sensitively. We have two options here:
>
> - teach callers to set ignore_case on the whole list
> - replace the ref_sorting list with a struct that contains both the list of sorting keys, as well as options that apply to *all* keys
>
> I went with the first one here, as it gives more flexibility if we later want to let the users set the flag per-key (presumably through some special syntax when defining the key; for now it's all or nothing through `--ignore-case`).
>
> The new test covers this by sorting on both tagger and subject case-insensitively, which should compare "`a`" and "`A`" identically, but still sort them before "`b`" and "`B`".
>   We'll break ties by sorting on the refname to give ourselves a stable output (this is actually supposed to be done automatically, but there's another bug which will be fixed in the next commit).