# Remote branch exists, local branch disappeared

Tags: git, github, branch

Ok, so the context is that im working on my own branch, creating a feature for a certain project.

My branch is called Exif (capital E) and today i accidentally did

```
git push origin exif  (lowercase e)
```

so it created a new branch for me called exif

After I realized this , I did

```
$ git push origin --delete exif
$ git branch -d exif
```

effectively deleting the branch again.
I have to add that I executed these 2 lines while I was checked out inside Exif (capital E), But that shouldn't matter right?

Now, when I execute

```
git status
```

I get a huge list saying that every file inside the whole project is a new file

When I try

```
git log
```

It says , you're current branch doesn't have any commits yet

when I do

```
git branch -a
```

all branches are there, except Exif, its also not in the remote branch list

but on our gitlab server it shows the branch just fine like nothing happened.

Does anyone have any idea what happened here?

**EDIT:**

In eclipse it shows an asterix next to every file, meaning that every file is staged.

In eclipse it also shows next to the root project folder that the project has [NO-HEAD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting a branch, git is not case sensitive, meaning your branch "Exif" would be deleted if you executed

```
git branch -d exif
```

You didn't even create a branch "Exif" in the first place, because by pushing to a different branch, you don't create that branch in your local repository automatically.

To go back to your original branch, I would create a new local branch by checking out the remote branch again like so:

```
git checkout origin/exif
```

Comment: ok so if i understand correctly, i deleted the local version of my branch, meaning i am currently inside a non-existant branch? because i am in Exif for the moment. But i still have a lot of changed files from todays work, do u suggest i just copy those files and then paste them back in once i checked out the remote branch?

Comment: if you have uncommited changes I would first stash them as described in the official git manual: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing .Then I would check out the remote branch and apply the stash on the checked out branch.

Comment: when i try to git stash it says fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'  fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'  fatal: needed a single revision  you do not have the initial commit yet

Comment: it seems you are not working on any branch right now. try to create a branch locally and set it up to follow the remote branch like so:  git branch --track exif origin/exif. you can do a backup of your folder first to ensure nothing is accidentely deleted.

Comment: Git *is* case sensitive; the problem comes in when Git is used on a system (Windows, Mac) that is *not* case sensitive, and Git become confused because it thinks it's fine to delete `exif` which is different from the current `Exif` (because *Git* is case-sensitive), but that deletes `Exif` (because *the OS* fails to be case-sensitive). This is a bug in Git, albeit one difficult to overcome without some reworking that probably waits for Git 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer here is not quite right, although this:

> but on our gitlab server it shows the branch just fine like nothing happened.

is promising and hence you may have an easy way to fix things.

I'll show an example where I destroy my own `master` branch (in a clone of course).  Since this particular system is case-sensitive I just hand-removed the `master` branch (behind Git's back, as it were).

#### The Git bug: branch names are case sensitive, except when they're not

This is a bug in Git: it managed to delete the branch you were standing on.

The problem occurs because Git *is* case-sensitive: the branch `exif` is, as far as Git is concerned, entirely separate from the branch `Exif`.  When you asked Git to delete `exif` it, in essence, checked:

- Am I on branch `exif`?
- If so, reject the attempt because it will screw everything up.
- Otherwise, go ahead and delete `exif`.

So Git checked, and it saw that your current branch was `Exif`, not `exif`.  Well, to Git, those are clearly *different*, it must be safe to delete!  Only ... they're not, and it's not.  [The truth is complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38494084/1256452), but on Windows and MacOS systems, Git either needs some implementation changes—so that branch names really *can* be case-sensitive, all the time—or Git needs to *stop believing* that they are case-sensitive because they sometimes (usually, on these systems) aren't.

## Fixing it

In the meantime, the tricky part is recovering your branch.  This requires a bit of delving into Git internals.

#### The two parts

Within Git, there are two key components to the current branch.  One is the file `.git/HEAD`.  This file contains a simple string:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
$
```

That is, this file contains (as plain text: not "rich text", not Unicode, not Windows UCS-2 format, just simple ASCII text) the literal string `ref: refs/heads/`, with one space before `refs/heads/`, followed by the name of the branch, followed by a newline.  This file is unharmed!

The other half is more complicated.  The good news is most of the complication goes away, because if it hadn't, the branch name would be case sensitive "the rest of the way" and you might (or might not) still be OK.  But this:

```
$ git log
fatal: your current branch 'Exif' does not have any commits yet
```

proves the branch value was stored only in the file `.git/refs/heads/branchname`.

That is, you used to have a file named:

```
.git/refs/heads/Exif
```

which had some hash value in it, something like this one (but with a different hash):

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
3ab228137f980ff72dbdf5064a877d07bec76df9
```

What we need to do is to put that file back, with that same value.

#### Fixing it: if you have the value (or part of it)

If you can *see* the value—or even just part of it—somewhere, e.g., in an existing window, that is sufficient to get the whole value back.  For instance, if I have `3ab228` showing somewhere I can do this:

```
$ git rev-parse 3ab228
3ab228137f980ff72dbdf5064a877d07bec76df9
```

which lets me do this to fix things:

```
$ git rev-parse 3ab228 > .git/refs/heads/master
```

and we're done.  (See the last item below about reflogs.)

#### Fixing it: if you have it as a remote-tracking branch

If you have successfully pushed the branch earlier, you may have the value as a remote-tracking branch:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
3ab228137f980ff72dbdf5064a877d07bec76df9
```

In this case you can put that back in place:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master > .git/refs/heads/master
```

and you're done.  (See the last item below about reflogs.)

#### Fixing it: if your upstream has it

In your case it sounds like the remote named `origin` has the right hash ID under the name `exif` (all lower-case), i.e., for some reason it ignored the `git push --delete` command.  In this case, you can ask the remote for the value.  Note that anyone else *might* have updated it since then:

```
$ git ls-remote origin master
454cb6bd52a4de614a3633e4f547af03d5c3b640        refs/heads/master
```

(clearly my remote has moved on, so I would not be able to use this, but if you're lucky yours has not).  Make sure the value is good:

```
$ git rev-parse 454cb6bd
454cb6bd
fatal: ambiguous argument '454cb6bd': unknown revision or path
 not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

(so this doesn't work for me, because they have indeed moved on).

As a last resort, you can run:

```
$ git fsck --unreachable
```

which is likely to spit out a whole lot of `unreachable` messages:

```
unreachable commit fcfbe9a1165e38467b4d24d41b3166a20c1dfb80
unreachable commit c8056a11ef8eee1bfaaaa2e32a9cc92a02eae2e0
unreachable blob 010a1a22a90b2bd78e6b87a3922c3324c44a8a9b
unreachable commit c1163ad1eeff0c86f030483907ea8cedcdd431e3
unreachable commit f35fc21adeb21e1a4800ccebd5719317efb968dc
```

Ignore everything but the "commit"s: one of those is the right one.  To find out which one, run `git show` on each one, perhaps with something to help shorten them a bit, e.g.:

```
$ git show --pretty=oneline --no-patch fcfbe9a1165e38467b4d24d41b3166a20c1dfb80
fcfbe9a1165e38467b4d24d41b3166a20c1dfb80 WIP on precious: e59f6c2 The last
 minute bits of fixes
```

(this shows that this particular item was actually a `git stash` commit).

When you find the right one, you can put it into `.git/refs/heads/Exif` to restore the value, and your repository will be mostly back in shape.  The `git rev-parse` method works here too, although since you have the full raw hash, you don't really have to `rev-parse` it.

## The reflog is gone; and where else you might look

Restoring the branch file fixes up the branch and makes everything ready again, e.g.:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However, the reflog for the branch is now gone:

```
$ git reflog master
$
```

The reflog for `HEAD` still works, and once you do a few more things on your branch, the reflog for the branch will be re-created.

If your file system gets backed up—e.g., via MacOS Time Machine, or by doing snapshots on a Windows network drive, or some such—you can look at your system backups.  If you are lucky, you may find both the branch file *and* the reflog in these backups.

In this case, you can simply restore them in place.  This has the same effect as finding the correct hash, but by restoring the reflog, you get your reflog back.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort u put into this answer, but i did what the other guy said, i fetched the remote Exif and created a new local branch that tracks the remote one, and i think it worked. Do you think there is something wrong with this simpler method, am i overlooking something?

Comment: @jelte: no, given that you had what you needed on the remote, you could use that method. But this bug could bite others, perhaps others who haven't done a `git push`, so I figured I would write up a way to deal with the bug until Git can be at least patched, if not outright fixed.