# Git branch name on mac

Tags: git, macos, rename, git-branch

I created the following branch on my MAC machine: `DevTasks/dev`
Did some stuff and committed. 
I had to rename the branch to `devTasks/dev`. I am not able to do that.

When I run

```
git branch -m DevTasks/dev devTasks/dev
```

I received "a branch name devTasks/dev is already exists"

I also removed completely the branch `DevTasks/dev` and created the new branch `devTasks/dev`. This also did not help.

Is it possible to rename branch name to the same branch name with capital letters on a Mac?

Comment: I know there is a way to change it via .git/refs/head for example :
mv .git/refs/head/DevTasks .git/refs/head/devTasks. I am not sure if it is safe or can cause other problems

Comment: Couldn't you just choose a totally different name?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493543/git-branch-name-case-sensitive-or-insensitive

Comment: The problem is, as @MincongHuang noted in a comment above (I'm not sure if StackOverflow will delete the comment if this gets closed as a duplicate), that on the Mac, branch names are sometimes (but not always!) case insensitive. See my answer to the other question for details.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [case sensitive nature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38494084/6309) of branches on Mac, the safest workaround would be to:

- rename `DevTasks/dev` into `devTasks/dev2`
- making sure `.git/refs/head/dev` no longer exist
- then rename `devTasks/dev2` into `devTasks/dev`