# Git branch delete deletes my branch where i currently staing on when name was written with diferent case

Tags: git

I just created new branch with name daco.

```
git checkout -b daco
```

Then i try delete it. I know it will be error and it was.

```
git branch -D daco
```

Error:
Cannot delete branch 'daco'

But when i try delete this way:

```
git branch -D Daco
```

It is deleted without problem.

Do you know why?

[image]

Comment: It seems a bug in a case-insensitive system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a artifact of a *case insensitive* file system, like that on Windows. Git internally stores branches as files and directories, inside the `.git/refs` folder.

So, when you create a branch named `foo`, a file named `foo` is created inside the `refs/heads` folder. Since you did it from a `checkout` command, git also records that `foo` is now the checked out branch. So, when you try to delete branch `foo`, git sees that `foo` is the checked out branch and gives you an error.

Now, when you try to delete branch named `Foo`, git first checks if a file named `Foo` exists in the `refs/heads` folder, and here is where it gets weird:

Since your file system is *case insensitive*, `Foo`, as a file name, is equivalent `foo`. Therefore, the file system reports that path `refs/heads/Foo` exists, when it’s actually `refs/heads/foo`. But then, when git checks if `Foo` is the checked out branch, it sees that `Foo` is *not* the checked out branch, because `foo` is, since git is internally *case sensitive*, for it `"Foo"` is *not* equal to `"foo"`. So, git wrongly determines that: `foo` is a existent branch, distinct from `Foo`, *and* that `Foo` is *not* the checked out branch. Therefore, git allows you to delete `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, git branches act case-insensitive because your underlying OS filesystem is case-insensitive (git branches are represented as files inside `.git/`). Git lets you delete 'Daco' because it sees that as a separate branch name, but the OS treats it as the same file, so Git ends up deleting the original 'daco'.

The answer from "torek" [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493543/git-branch-name-case-sensitive-or-insensitive) has some good details. The file names that represent Git branches "are case-insensitive, e.g. case-preserving, but fold case during name-matching." Basically, Git is case-sensitive and your OS is probably case-insensitive, which results in being able to delete a nonexistent branch with the capitalized name of an existing branch. I tested it on my Mac and I get the same results as you.