# Is there anyway to recover deleted branch from bitbucket done through IntelliJ

Tags: java, git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I have created two branch with the same `feature/Dev23` and `feature/dev23`.

At the time of checkout in IntelliJ I was getting "`there exist a branch with the same name`".

So I deleted one (`feature/Dev23`) and checkout the new `feature/dev23`.
But now I want this branch as well.

I am expecting the branch to be seen in Bitbucket and retrieve it properly.

Answer (score 0):

> But now I want this branch as well.

From a command line, check the output of [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): you can use said output to [recover a deleted branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019083/6309) (assuming it was deleted recently)

```
git switch -c feature/old-Dev23 HEAD@{**number**}
```

If `feature/Dev23` is not listed in reflog (because you never switch to it), check the output of `git branch -avv`, and:

```
git switch -c feature/old-Dev23 origin/Dev23
```

Note I use a different name to re-create the branch, that way it does not interfere with your new `feature/dev23`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38494084/6309) bon branch name case sensitivity.