# Unknown git branch checked out

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a branch called `ChartFeature` but I accidentally typed `git checkout CHartFeature` and ended up with this in powershell/poshgit:

```
C:\git\Charting [CHartFeature]> git status
On branch CHartFeature
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What happened here? If I look in SourceTree it does not show the branch, but I can (and got myself into trouble) when I committed files to this branch which I never created. (I never typed `git checkout -b CHartFeature` but I did need to merge it into `ChartFeature`.)

If I list the local branches this erroneous branch does not exist:

```
C:\git\Charting [CHartFeature]> git branch
  ChartFeature
  develop
  master
```

What is git doing when I type `git checkout CHartFeature` without having created that branch? What happened to the commits I made there?

What's more, is it safe to type `git branch -d CHartFeature`? What would happen if I did?

Comment: are you using windows ?

Comment: This looks like some else created this branch sometime ago and pushed it accidentially.

Comment: If you're on Windows, where file names are (normally) not case sensitive, you can checkout any case combination of the branch it seems but you're still on the correctly named branch. I just checked out `MAster`, committed a change and checked the log, it looks OK, then I checked out `master`, checked the log and my commit is present. I assume that `git checkout X` just checks if there is a file that can be opened under the refs folder with that name, and on Windows there is, even if the actual filename is `x`.

Comment: @LeGEC yes, Windows 7

Comment: @ckruczek Nope, definitely not.

Comment: Note that if I look in the `.git\refs\heads` folder I now have a file named `MAster` which tracks the head of the branch, if I push I assume that the remote repository might not be so "forgiving". In other words, it seems case insensitivity is the reason here but it is not safe to do.

Comment: On Windows those commands are case-insensitive, so you are basically using the intended branch just with a different name. However, you'll probably face problems with `push` because casing matters there, so you will want to fix the case by renaming the file as @phts said in his answer.

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen The branch list and commits appear to show that I was committing to a different branch. What you've said makes sense, but it is disturbing seeing that I needed to resolve the merge conflict on the intended branch, because I had something like 15 commits to merge across. If it was committing to the intended branch, typo-aside, surely the conflicts would not exist.

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen To your last comment, yes... When I (not yet realising the mistake) tried to push, git complained that I should type git push --set-upstream origin CHartFeature

Comment: @lasse-v-karlsen Post your info as an answer and I'll tick it. You're right.

Comment: Git is somewhat confused about whether to be case-sensitive or case-insensitive with branch names. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38494084/1256452) and [VonC's more recent note about Git 2.12](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41307509/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

Seems this issue due to case sensitiveness in Windows.

Try to rename `./.git/refs/heads/CHartFeature` to `ChartFeature` manually. Or any `CHartFeature` presented in `.git` folder.

Comment: The recommended way to rename a branch is using `git branch -m`, not by manually fixing things inside the `.git` folder.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen in theory `git branch -m` shouldn't work, since a branch with a different name was never created. The OP used `git checkout` without the `-b` option.

Comment: Manual renaming is a little tricky as you should also rename the *reflog* file (`.git/logs/refs/heads/CHartFeature`). @kopranb: the `-b` is automatically assumed if there is one (and only one) matching `origin/*` remote-tracking branch. In this case, there was.

Comment: @torek indeed, but it didn't really create a branch since `git branch` doesn't list it. I'm not sure how the OP got merge conflicts though, since his commits should have changed the tip of the branch with the correct name.

Comment: @kopranb: I don't have his system, but I think the problem here is that it *did* create a branch, in the sort of split-brain manner that happens here: parts of Git believe the two branch names are different, and treat them as different, and parts believe they are the same and treat them that way, and the end result is bad behavior.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38494084/1256452 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/41307509/1256452 as well. I think this is going to get fixed soonish in a new Git.

Answer (score 0):

Check what branches exist on your repo :

```
git branch
git branch -r  # view remote branches
```

If `CHartFeature` exists, but `ChartFeature` doesn't, try renaming your current branch :

```
git branch -m ChartFeature
```

Comment: @MattW: among the following branches : `ChartFeature`, `CHartfeature`, `origin/ChartFeature`, `origin/CHartFeature`, which ones do you see ?

Comment: See comments on OP